# Set-UMMailbox not listed in Exchange Powershell session?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

When creating a new PS Session to our Exchange 2010 server:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName microsoft.exchange -ConnectionURI http://exchange.domain.com/powershell -Credential $cred
```

And importing the newly created session:

```
Import-PSSession $session
```

This would give me a slew of Exchange cmdlets that I can now use locally within my Powershell session. Unfortunately, it seems to be missing a few cmdlets that I need to automate some mailbox actions. Specifically -- **Set-UMMailbox**, which would allow me to change the operator's phone number on the mailbox.

Is this a bug with this particular configuration? Or am I missing something else?

If there is another way go to about doing this, I'm all ears. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a difference in OS or PowerShell version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue here is related to permissions. The service account I was using had a majority of the rights, but not rights to unified messaging. I tested this by using my domain admin account credentials (which I won't be using in my script).